# flex-grow won't resize in proportion

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a responsive site which has either a 2 column layout or 3 column layout.

I am using flex-box as further down the line I would like to set an order sequence to them.

I would like the boxes to fill the maximum available space.

Flexbox works perfectly except the images will not resize proportionately (as you can see in my code) Usually I would apply a 100% width and padding-bottom % to a div but flex-box items won't seem to allow this method.

If it helps, the images are all 300px wide. I tried applying the flex-box class to the images as I had hoped I might have more luck. Not yet...

Any advice would be great.

```
      <div class="flex-container">
             <img class="flex-item" src="image.png"   alt=""/>
             <img class="flex-item" src="image.png"   alt=""/>
             <img class="flex-item" src="image.png"   alt=""/>
             <img class="flex-item" src="image.png"   alt=""/>
             <img class="flex-item" src="image.png"   alt=""/>
             <img class="flex-item" src="image.png"   alt=""/>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color:#99C;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;

}


.flex-item {
      flex-grow:1;
}
```

Comment: You want to retain the image width and height and not stretch. Am I right with this?

Comment: I would like the image to grow and shrink while constraining its proportions. Responsive but without distortion. Thanks!

Comment: Use media screen for different viewports and make your image responsive..

Comment: I really wanted flew-box for it's order capabilities. I am really surprised that this isn't a common issue considering flex-box would be used for image grids all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Add wrapper to image:

```
<div class="flex-item">
<img src="%path%" />
</div>
```

And css

```
img{
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ea2xh9we/

Comment: Unfortunately while the image proportions stay relative, which is what I want, they are no longer in a grid, but rather just one image per row.

Comment: Did you open fiddle link? This code put all relative image in same row and it works fine in FF, Chrome and IE10+. Flex make all ``.flex-item`` container same size and  then fill images to 100% of their width and set height by auto. Another version of fiddle with different size of images: http://jsfiddle.net/ea2xh9we/1/

Comment: Hey there, I did, but it only showed one, really wide image. This one works better though in the end up went with plain floated elements and media queries. I had wanted to use the order property but I gave up. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Ahh I'm such a muppet, I have just realised it's not one long images, there is just no margins. Sorry - what an idiot. I may revert back to this :)

Comment: Your code was without margins, I made too similar as possible : )